# reference request for logarithm of linear operator

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, functional-analysis

Are there some reference books that talks about the logarithm of linear operator.For example given a banach space $X$ (over $\Bbb{R}$ or $\Bbb{C}$) and a bounded linear operator on $L \in \mathcal{L}(X)$,does the logarithm exist,and when it's unique or not?I don't even know how to define the logarithm.

This question seems out of standard textbook in functional analysis,is there some reference books talk about those questions?

Comment: Have  a look at Douglas' "Banach Algebra techniques in Operator Theory". He talks about when an element in a Banach algebra can be written in the form $\exp(a)$ (early in Chapter 2).